# Make custom checkout required field created by plugin optional in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, custom-fields

In woocommerce checkout page need to remove a specific custom field validation. This field is basically generated by a plugin using woocommerce_form_field().Is there any way to remove the validation for that specific field?The piece of code block

```
echo '<div id="woo_delivery_delivery_selection_field" style="display:none;">';
            woocommerce_form_field('woo_delivery_delivery_selection_box',
            [
                'type' => 'select',
                'class' => [
                    'woo_delivery_delivery_selection_box form-row-wide'
                ],
                'label' => __($delivery_option_field_label, 'woo-delivery'),
                'placeholder' => __($delivery_option_field_label, 'woo-delivery'),
                'options' => Woo_Delivery_Delivery_Option::delivery_option($delivery_option_settings),
                'required' => true,
                'custom_attributes' => [
                    'data-no_result_notice' => __($no_result_notice, 'woo-delivery'),
                ],
            ], WC()->checkout->get_value('woo_delivery_delivery_selection_box'));
        echo '</div>'
```

Comment: yes, if the JS validation is added or otherwise you need to update the code to remove server-side or PHP validation.

Comment: How I can override? What piece of code I need to write in functions.php

Comment: You need also to provide in your question, the code that is used for field validation  by your plugin… Without that nobody can't really answer your question. **For info,** checkout field validation can be handled by the following hooks: `woocommerce_after_checkout_validation` or `woocommerce_checkout_process`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to test the code like it into your `functions.php` of child or active theme

---

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'remove_validation_from_field', PHP_INT_MAX, 1 );
 
function remove_validation_from_field( $woo_checkout_fields_array ) {
    // use unset to remove the validation from your desired field
    // like I am removing the phone number validation from billing address
    unset( $woo_checkout_fields_array['billing']['billing_phone']['validate'] );
    return $woo_checkout_fields_array;
}
```

Comment: How I can have the checkout custom field inside $woo_checkout_fields_array? My custom field is select type. Can I write like this:
unset( $woo_checkout_fields_array['my_custom_field_name']['validate'] ); Will it work for me?Please suggest

Comment: You need to print the ```$woo_checkout_fields_array``` to get all available checkout fields and then copy the name of your custom field.

Comment: Inside the add_filter callback function can I use print_r($woo_checkout_fields_array)?

Comment: yes, inside the callback you use it like ```print_r($woo_checkout_fields_array);```

Comment: Sorry, but the print_r() only showing billing,shipping and order array details not my custom field in the print_r output. My custom field is actually after billing form and that custom field is wrapped around a form.

Comment: it's strange, you are able to attach the snapshot of ```print_r()``` and name if plugin and field that is added to your website?

Answer (score -1):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'woocommerce_form_fields' );
                
function  woocommerce_form_fields( $fields ) {
$fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['required'] = false;
return $fields;
}
```

Actually we need use filter hook woocommerce_checkout_fields and need to modified based on billing,shiping,account,orders.
For more details you may visit https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/
thank you

Comment: Can I write this code directly inside functions.php without using any filter or hook?

Comment: Yes you need to use filter woocommerce_checkout_fields in functions.php